# rack application, params as key

Tags: ruby, post, request, rack

I'm requesting rack application with

```
curl -X POST -d '{"device":{"username":"123456","name":"some name","location":"Hidden"}}' http://localhost:9292/device
```

In the rack application I'm creating request object

```
request = Rack::Request.new(env)
```

And I'm expecting that POST data will be in params hash

```
request.params => should be a normal hash
```

but somehow it's not quite correct. I got params in this format

```
{{"device":{"username":"123456","name":"some name","location":"Hidden"}}=>nil}
```

So the params data which I needed became a key of hash. Why is that and how to make it normalhash like this

```
{"device":{"username":"123456","name":"some name","location":"Hidden"}}
```

? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normally `-d` expects data to be passed in `var=val` format, and as you did not pass `var` it transforms your data to `var` and assign a empty string to it.

when you using `curl` like this you get following params:

```
 params = {'{"device":{"username":"123456","name":"some name","location":"Hidden"}}'=>nil}
```

then you simply parse it as json:

```
require 'json'

JSON.parse params.keys.first    
=> {"device"=>{"username"=>"123456", "name"=>"some name", "location"=>"Hidden"}}
```

**alternatively you can pass params like this:**

```
curl -X POST -d 'json={"device":{"username":"123456","name":"some name","location":"Hidden"}}' :9292
```

then you get following params:

```
params = {'json'=>'{"device":{"username":"123456","name":"some name","location":"Hidden"}}'}
```

and simply parse into `JSON`:

```
JSON.parse(params['json'])

#=> {"device"=>{"username"=>"123456", "name"=>"some name", "location"=>"Hidden"}}
```

Comment: I'm just using 'request.params.keys.first', but I think it's not generally correct.

Comment: Can I get just a string and then parse it into hash?